# Black-Scholes Model for options pricing

Tags: stochastic-calculus, finance

The Black-Scholes pricing formula for a European call option is given by:

$$C(S,t) = SN(d_+) - E\exp(-r(T-t))N(d_-)$$

where $S\ge0$ is the spot price, $t\le T$ is the time,$T\ge0$ is the expiry date, $E\ge0$ is the strike, and

$$d_{\pm}=\frac{\log(S/E) + (r-D\pm\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(T-t))}{\sigma\sqrt{T-t}}$$

where

$$N(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^x_{-\infty}\exp(-\phi^2)d\phi$$

$r\ge0$ the interest rate, $D$ the dividend yield, $\sigma$ the volatility of $S$.
With these assumptions, how can we show the following equation:

$$S\exp(-d_+^2/2)=E\exp(-r(T-t))\exp(-d_{-}^2/2)$$

and what is the intuition/interpretation of it?

Comment: With all the definition you have given you should be able to verify in  a straightforward manner if that equation is true. Please make some attempts.

Comment: I tried expanding the equation using the definition of $d_{+-}$ but I am not sure how to connect it to the pricing formulas. Do you have some hints?

Comment: Hi @lavendar_shortbread, welcome to MSE! Please edit your question showing your attempt. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to familiarise yourself with the site's rules.

Comment: @lavendar_shortbread . The equation you are trying to show -if true- should hold irrespective of the pricing formula. Did you manage to show it ? We need to see attempts in detail.